# How to copy a formula from "Parent Tab" to "Child Tab" on Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm doing RolePlay Character Sheets on a "Parent tab" I've called "MODEL", where I masterize my formulas.

I've created a second tab "Character1" and a third one "Character2". But when I try to use =QUERY or =TEXTFORMULA or whatever. It doesn't make the formulas to calculate on the actual spreadsheet, it just get the data from the "MODEL" tab.

My only way is actually to copy/past all my formulas, but if I do a mistake, I'll have to correct it in every spreadsheet every time.

Is that possible to have a formula which take the cell at:

- MODELE!AE58

And automatically generate the same formulas in every tabs:

- CHARACTER1!AE58
- CHARACTER2!AE58
- etc...

Sorry if its blur, I'm doing my best to explain.

Comment: Can you share a spreadsheet with 3 tabs (model and 2 others) and some formulas. You will probably need getFormulas and the batchupdate within all the tabs.

Comment: You'r insightful ! :D

Comment: Just see this test you've done and implant it, it don't replace actually formulas, it seem to work anyway, I've certainly wrong manage something !

Comment: I've think about that and retracted them few minutes ago, so it seem no

Comment: EDIT : Was my mistake, it seem to be fully automatic.

~~Yeah, I see that. But when it come to AE81 for example. I'm trying to do the same as you and it don't work. Is that supposed to be automatic or did I need to use the "MENU" thing you add to my shortcuts ? :X~~

Comment: It work perfectly, the mistake was human. All is perfect, thanks so much. Can I offer you a tips or a coffee ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### simple

Try

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  var rng = e.source.getActiveRange()
  if (rng.getFormula() != '' && sh.getName() == 'MODEL') {
    var excl = ['MODEL', 'OTHER'];//excluded sheets
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(sh => {
      if (!~excl.indexOf(sh.getSheetName())) {
        sh.getRange(rng.getA1Notation()).setFormula(rng.getFormula())
      }
    })
  }
}
```

when you change a formula in MODEL, this will also change in other tabs excepts excluded ones

### multiple

If you edit the formulas by dragging them into the MODEL sheet, use this one which allows you to edit all the formulas at once

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sh = e.source.getActiveSheet()
  if (sh.getName() != 'MODEL') return;
  for (var i = e.range.rowStart; i <= e.range.rowEnd; i++) {
    for (var j = e.range.columnStart; j <= e.range.columnEnd; j++) {
      if (sh.getRange(i, j).getFormula() != '') {
        var excl = ['MODEL', 'OTHER'];//excluded sheets
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(child => {
          if (!~excl.indexOf(child.getSheetName())) {
            child.getRange(sh.getRange(i, j).getA1Notation()).setFormula(sh.getRange(i, j).getFormula())
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### global

Il you need to reset all formulas, **enable google sheets api** and try

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('⇩ M E N U ⇩')
    .addItem(' Apply all formulas from MODEL to all tabs', 'spreadFormulas')
    .addToUi();
}
function spreadFormulas() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('MODEL')
  if (sh.getName() != 'MODEL') return;
  var data = [];
  var formulas = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getFormulas()
  for (var i = 0; i < formulas.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < formulas[0].length; j++) {
      if (formulas[i][j] != '') {
        var excl = ['MODEL', 'OTHER'];//excluded sheets
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(child => {
          if (!~excl.indexOf(child.getSheetName())) {
            data.push({
              range: `${child.getName()}!${columnToLetter(+j + 1) + (+i + 1)}`,
              values: [[`${formulas[i][j]}`]],
            })
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
  if (data.length) {
    var resource = {
      valueInputOption: 'USER_ENTERED',
      data: data,
    };
    try { Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId()); } catch (e) { console.log(JSON.stringify(e)) }
  }
}
function columnToLetter(column) {
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0) {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

Comment: It seem to be the right way to do it. But i'm a little newbie :X. Can you, please, let me know what I've to edit and where ? I'm reading javascript, but this one is a bit too complicate for my bad level :3

Comment: I've just add the "Global" script to my Apps Scripts extension and replace the occurrences of MODEL by MODELE. The execution doesn't find any error, so it seem perfect. But it doesn't replace anything ATM. I've reset the permission for everyone able to edit. (And do a copy, we never now !).

Comment: I'm not supposed to say to the script the cells it need to copy ? If it see a formula, he'll copy it ? :)

Comment: In the first or second proposal (you have to choose one of them, not implement both), when you change a formula in MODEL, this formula will also put automatically in other tabs, except thoses mentionned in excl? Be aware of protections in your sheets.

Comment: For the third proposal (global), I addes a menu, you don't have to indicate any formulas, all the formules contained in MODEL will be put automatically in other tabs, except thoses mentionned in excl? Be aware of protections in your sheets.

Answer (score 0):

if your sheet is called `MODELE` try on some other sheet just:

```
=MODELE!AE58
```

for array it would be:

```
={MODELE!AE58:AE100}
```

also take a look into "Named Ranges" - maybe you will find it more handy

Comment: This one dont work cause its resolve the formula on the mode sheet.

If the formula is A=1+A2. 
On the MODEL, A2 = 20, result will be 21
On the COPY, A2 = 100, result will be 21

The result on both will be = 21